# Encrypt file names in archives, prevent showing content list with ionic.zip in c#

Tags: encryption, dotnetzip, ionic-zip

I know zipping files with ionic.zip like here:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.Password = "123";
    zip.AddDirectory("/path/");
    zip.SaveProgress += Zip_ProgressBar;
    zip.Save("/path/");
}
```

But this code allows people to see encrypted files and folders names. What can I do to prevent archived (encrypted) file and folder names from appearing?

Comment: The zip format do not support encrypted filenames - but you can get the effect if you use two layers of zip files where the inner zip file is encrypted.

Comment: I think you can use .NetZip firstly, and than [file encryption](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/471/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-the-aes-encryption-algorithm-in-c-sharp).

Comment: similar question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289999/how-to-zip-directory-with-encryption-for-file-names